# How to check if "Everyone" has full control permissions to a file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am writing a utility to help with changing file permissions on a certain file to allow/disallow access to it for the "Everyone" group on a Windows machine.  So far I have been able to set and remove the Full Control permissions for "Everyone" to the file by using this code:

```
void AddFullControl()
{
    FileSecurity fsFile = File.GetAccessControl("file.tmp");
    fsFile.SetAccessRule( new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
    File.SetAccessControl("file.tmp", fsFile);
}

void RemoveFullControl()
{
    FileSecurity fsFile = File.GetAccessControl("file.tmp");
    fsFile.SetAccessRule( new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
    File.SetAccessControl("file.tmp", fsFile);
}
```

However, I want to check to see if "Everyone" already has the Full Control permission or not and have not been able to find a way to do this.  I have spent several days scouring through Google search after Google search and have not been able to find a way to do this.  Can someone point me in the right direction or give me an example of how to do this please?

**Update:**
This was answered very quickly and I was able to come up with c# code that works.  The code I created is as follows:

```
void CheckAccess()
{
    AuthorizationRuleCollection arcFile = File.GetAccessControl("file.tmp").GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
    foreach (AuthorizationRule arFile in arcFile)
    {
        if (arFile.IdentityReference.Value == "Everyone")
        {
            FileSystemAccessRule fasrFile = (FileSystemAccessRule)arFile;
            if (fasrFile.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow && fasrFile.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("file.tmp already has Full Control permissions granted to Everyone");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `RemoveFullControl` is not doing what you probably intended it to.  Rather than removing the Everyone access it is explicitly denying access to Everyone, including the operating system and administrators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var everyone = fsFile.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier))
    .Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.IdentityReference.Value == "S-1-1-0");
bool fullControlAllowed = everyone != null
             && everyone.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow
             && everyone.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl);
```

If permissions might include both `Allow` and `Deny` entries for `Everyone`, you will have to use code like the following. It has slightly different semantics, since you don't get the details on `everyone` `Deny` entries.

```
var everyone = fsFile.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier))
    .Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.IdentityReference.Value == "S-1-1-0"
                       && x.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow);
bool fullControlAllowed = everyone != null
             && everyone.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!  Once I converted this to c# code it works like a charm! :D

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the authorization rules for the file and check to see if there's a rule for the "Everyone" account.  Then you can check the `FileSystemRights` for the rule to see if it has `FullControl`.

```
var account = @"Everyone";
var hasFullControl = rules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>()
    .Where(rule => rule.IdentityReference.Value == account && rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
    .Select(rule => (bool?)rule.FileSystemRights.HasFlag(FileSystemRights.FullControl))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

A file which is restricted to 'Everyone' which otherwise cannot be recognized through the command `if(Directory.Exists(pathfile))` because the file is access protected, the compiler wouldn't recognize its presence in the specified Directory and it will always hit the `!Directory.Exists(pathfile)` command.
If you want to write new data every time, then this may help,

```
string pathfile = @"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Filepath.txt";
if (!Directory.Exists(pathfile))
{
    File.SetAttributes(pathfile, FileAttributes.Normal);
    File.Delete(pathfile);

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pathfile))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("What Ever Your Text is");

        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
        File.SetAttributes(pathfile, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        FileSecurity fsec = File.GetAccessControl(pathfile);
        fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone",
        FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow));
        File.SetAccessControl(pathfile, fsec);
    }
}
```